# How can i get the number of an image of a certain sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I randomly share pictures of houses on the screen. Then I drive a car across the screen.When the car hits a house, the image of that house should be replaced with a modified copy of that house.
I distribute the images with the following function

```
while len(land) < anzahl_gegenstaende:
        ii = len(land)
        img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png").convert_alpha() 
        zb,zh = img.get_rect().size
        scale_hoehe =100
        scale_breite = int(100 * zb / zh)        
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(scale_breite,scale_hoehe))            
        m = Landschaft(img)
        
        if not pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, land, False):           
            land.add(m)
```

I check the collision car with house

```
treffer = pygame.sprite.spritecollide( auto, land, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)    
  
for bumbs in treffer:
```

....
How do I then get the house number or picture number of the house that collided so that I can replace the picture with a slightly modified copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the image number in an attribute of the Sprite class:

```py
class Landschaft(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, ii):
        super().__init__() 
        self.img = img
        self.ii = ii
        # [...]
```

```py
while len(land) < anzahl_gegenstaende:
    ii = len(land)
    img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png").convert_alpha() 
    # [...]

    m = Landschaft(img, ii)
    if not pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, land, False):           
        land.add(m)
```

```py
treffer = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(auto, land, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)    
for bumbs in treffer: 
    ii = bomb.ii
    # [...]
```